# How to get the selected value in table

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

Here I want to do, on change the status I want get the value id and status, here I got only id, I can't get the status(1 or 2 or 3), I don't know how to do:-

```js
function get_pstatus(_this){
  var p_id=$(_this).closest('tr').find('#p_id').val();
  var p_status=$(_this).closest('tr').find('#p_status').text();
  console.log(p_status);  
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" id="">
<thead>
    <tr>
       <th>No.</th>
       <th>Project Name</th>
       <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <?php
 include('dbconfig.php');
 $project = mysql_query("SELECT id,project_id,project_name FROM add_projects WHERE status !='1'");
 for ($i=1;$p=mysql_fetch_assoc($project);$i++){
 ?>
 <tr class="odd gradeX">
  <td id="s_no"><?php echo $i;?><input id="p_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $p['id']?>"></td>
  <td id="p_name"><?php echo $p['project_name']?></td>
  <td id="p_status">
   <form style=" margin-bottom: 0px;" id="project_status">
   <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status" onchange="get_pstatus(this);" style="width:150px;">
      <option value="">-- Select Status --</option>
     <option value="1">one</option>
     <option value="2">two</option>
     <option value="3">three</option>
   </select>
   </form>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: post your jquery as well

Comment: On change the status that time i want to take that value like 1 or 2 or 3 and also i want to take id value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the selected option value and text both, so do like below:-

```
function get_pstatus(){
    var p_id = $('select#status').find('option:selected').val();
    var p_status = $('select#status').find('option:selected').text();   
}
```

Or

```
function get_pstatus(){
    var p_id = $('#status :selected').val();
    var p_status = $('#status :selected').text();
}
```

And instead of `onchange="get_pstatus(this);` write `onchange="get_pstatus();`

Example:-

```js
function get_pstatus(){
    var p_id = $('#status :selected').val();
    var p_status = $('#status :selected').text();
    console.log(p_id);
    console.log(p_status);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="status" name="status" onchange="get_pstatus(this);" style="width:150px;">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: p_status i am geting like this one-- Select Status --

Comment: How to remove that -- Select Status -- –

Comment: It's a select box so when you select different -different values there corresponding text comes. So if you don't want `-- Select Status --` . Then remove  `<option value="">-- Select Status --</option>`

Comment: this is one table in this table hidden field i pass the value="<?php echo $p['id']?>" how to take this value

Comment: @KaniR  don't ask new question again and again,learn some basics of jquery. You have that code already. `$('#p_id').val();`

Comment: @KaniR  please ask new question for others doubt.Thanks. BTW it will be `$('#p_name').text();`

Comment: K fine i got answer

Comment: @KaniR  thanks. Glad to help you.:):).Please upvote the answer too. Also read the previous comment before `K fine i got answer `. You will get the second question answer